# Easiest way ti implement SOAP WS client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jakarta-ee

- I'm about to iplement WS service
  client
- I have wsdl description
- Client itself is Spring 3.0.2
  application running in jetty
- (I'm doing some changes)
- Application is build by maven

WHAT IS THE SIMPLEST WAY TO IMPLEMENT THE CLIENT FROM WSDL?

(I'm thinking of some code generation from wsdl)
I don't want to add huge amount of dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WSDL2Code Plug-in](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/maven-plugins/maven-wsdl2code-plugin.html) to generate client is I found easier to use.

Comment: What additional dependencies must I add after generating sources?

Comment: Genrated sources have ant build? what the hell is that if I'm using the Maven

Comment: @Hundra Maven is far better than ant. you can  check the link provided to get answer for both of your questoins

Comment: life.java - I followed link did exactly what was there - run mvn axis2-wsdl2code:wsdl2code and all i got is generated code in target/generated-sources with ant build.xml - can you please elaborate on usage (like 10 steps to use this)